# install4j fails to download JDK archives from well-known OpenJDK providers

Tags: java, ssl, install4j

Install4j allows users to select a JDK for automatic download with the json property:

```
 <jreBundles jdkProviderId="Liberica" release="OpenJDK 11.0.6+10">
```

On my desktop I can dry run just fine and also fetch the jdk from the bellsoft-

However when I run dry run on my server I get the following error and the jdk cannot be fetched. I can download it in the browser online from the website without issues but not with the Install4j GUI.

```
> Creating JRE bundle:
>     Finding JDK release OpenJDK 11.0.6+10 [windows-amd64]
>     Downloading bellsoft-jdk11.0.6%2B10-windows-amd64.zip
> 
> Build failed.
> 
> Cause: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
>        Read timed out Stack trace:
> 
> com.exe4j.a.d: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read timed out     at
> com.install4j.b.o.b(ejt:237)  at com.install4j.gui.b.run(ejt:100)
> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read timed out     at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:259)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:137)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
>   at
> java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
>   at
> java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
>   at
> java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:163)
>   at
> com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.HttpRequestHandler.getURLConnection(HttpRequestHandler.java:288)
>   at
> com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.HttpRequestHandler.connect(HttpRequestHandler.java:135)
>   at
> com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.Downloader.connect(Downloader.java:155)
>   at
> com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.Downloader.connect(Downloader.java:24)
>   at
> com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.HttpRequestHandler.connect(HttpRequestHandler.java:128)
>   at
> com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.Downloader.connect(Downloader.java:150)
>   at com.install4j.jdk.h.a(ejt:282)   at com.install4j.jdk.h.a(ejt:19)
>   at com.install4j.jdk.j.a(ejt:153)   at
> com.install4j.jdk.j.invoke(ejt:19)    at
> com.install4j.jdk.aa$a.a(ejt:18)  at com.install4j.jdk.ak.a(ejt:61)
>   at com.install4j.jdk.h.b(ejt:140)   at com.install4j.jdk.h.a(ejt:97)
>   at com.install4j.b.i.a(ejt:35)  at com.install4j.b.c.h(ejt:942)     at
> com.install4j.b.c.a(ejt:909)  at com.install4j.b.c.W(ejt:890)     at
> com.install4j.b.o.a(ejt:490)  at com.install4j.b.o.b(ejt:166)     ... 1
> more Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out   at
> java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   at
> java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
>   at
> java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
>   at
> java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:448)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:165)
>   at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:108)
>   ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the build sever cannot make a connection to the server of the JDK provider, you can avoid the JRE bundle creation by transferring the relevant directories in

```
$HOME/.install4j/jres/generated
```

from your development machine to the build machine, then no download is required. This assumes that you have run the build for all media files on your development machine, so that all JRE bundles have been generated.

Comment: Yes I did this and it works. I was able to generate a jre bundle on the server even. This is however a workaround and not a solution to the root cause of my issue.

Comment: You could try to debug the SSL connection by adding `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` to `bin/install4j.vmoptions`. See https://access.redhat.com/solutions/973783

Comment: I added this to the file and got the same output in the gui, where will the addtional debug info be visible?

Comment: You would have to create a command line launcher to see this output.